# What is the difference between an integrator and a charge amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I looked up on the net and just found that a charge amplifier is an integrator with high input impedance, but an integrator is already supposed to have high input impedance itself, so I'm really confused at this point, any help would be apprecieated

Comment: Please post the circuits that you saw.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is a technical article on the web written by Robert Keim in 2018 that states that "a charge amplifier is an integrator with very high input impedance". I have a copy of this and I wonder if that is your reference?

I would disagree with this and suggest that a charge amplifier has almost zero input impedance. Maybe, when Robert talks about the input impedance he is referring to the impedance between the input and ground which is the input impedance of the actual op amp which is a very high value and must be high in a charge amplifier so that all of the current coming from the sensor reaches the feedback capacitor.

[image: Charge amplifier]

As can be seen in the the above diagram of a charge amplifier, the amplifier is operating with its inverting input held virtually at a constant 0V. So the input impedance which is equal to Vin/Iin is almost zero. The charge amplifier is receiving an almost uninhibited current and integrating it to produce an output which is proportional to the charge produced by, say, a piezoelectric transducer.

If we now consider a more conventional looking integrator...

[image: Integrator]

The input impedance in the above conventional integrator is defined by the value of R1.

Comment: I think you make a useful distinction. Your later case first converts a voltage to a current. I was dealing *only* with currents. But when I was working on (bite my tongue) 'charge amplifiers' (starting at the low femptoamp level through 8 more orders of magnitude above that -- beating Keithley's best equipment in one case I'm proud about) I never *once* thought of them as charge amplifiers. I always thought of them as integrators and spoke that way with the others I worked with. The only folks in those companies using 'charge amplifier' were in the technical marketing department.